# How do I prevent a crash when interacting with Blu-Ray videos?

Tags: crash, kernel-panic, blu-ray

I have a new M1 Pro Mac and I installed `ffmpeg` using `brew`. I also have a Blu-Ray ISO (contains `.m2ts` files) on standby to be converted to `.mkv`.

Previously on a Intel mac, I used this command and it worked fine, shrinking the size of the original file by a lot:

```
ffmpeg -i file.m2ts -c:v copy -crf 28 -c:a flac ~/desktop/mynew.mkv
```

When I do this on my M1; where I expect the 'encoding' to be faster, I get an astounding KERNEL PANIC!

I'm pretty sure `ffmpeg` isn't corrupted. I used `homebrew` to install it on `macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)`. The same command with a mp4 in place (test.m2ts -> test.mp4) does not crash. Performing `cp` on said `.m2ts` file (`cp test.m2ts ~/desktop/a.m2ts`) causes a panic. I have discovered that the problem is how each computer handles the `.m2ts` file. Same file on Intel and M1, except it causes a crash on M1.

So, what can I do in this situation? Do I wait for another Monterey update to fix this? I've also read that playing an HDR video causes a panic, however playing a Blu-Ray disc in VLC causes no crash.

For those interested in the Panic Log, here is a pastebin link of a crash caused by **FFMPEG**: https://pastebin.com/f1gemPQ2

and here is a crash with symbolication enabled, but caused by me **OPENING the folder with m2ts:** https://paste.ee/p/n65io

Comment: Can you please amend your question with a code block containing your panic report?

Comment: Why do you think it is not a problem with ffmpeg ?

Comment: I would be tempted to post this info (along with the panic report) to the FFMPEG discussion boards as well....

Comment: @pion the panic report isn't that special. TL;DR issue is with FFmpeg panicking in relation to `com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily` & `com.apple.filesystems.udf`.

@PtitXav @SteveChambers please read the part where I confirmed that it's *not* an issue with FFmpeg.

Comment: @Meh. I would nevertheless like to see the full report

Comment: I added a link, I'm not sure if the 'loaded kext' part is needed so I ended up omitting it

Comment: @Meh. So the crash signature on that second report is rather different (corrupted stack pointer) but because this is another memory management panic it may not be totally unrelated. I'm still not seeing backtrace symbols, though – can you please share what `sysctl kern.bootargs` says?

Comment: I can't be bothered with this; I change the bootargs, reenable csrutil and bootargs shows that it's been wiped. I will just go out to say that it is Apple's fault, and that waiting for a fix is the solution. I have submitted the bug to Apple via Feedback assistant, using the `cp` panic report, however it has no backtrace symbols.

Comment: I can reliably reproduce this issue since I upgrade my m1 max 16'' MBP to 12.2. Still hasn't been fixed on 12.3.1.

Comment: Here is something interesting to add: Turning off 'preview items' for all folders then navigating to a folder with `m2ts` files does not crash, probably because the Kernel Panic is caused by generating thumbnails. Opening it in VLC however causes a crash, but not when you drag the entire ISO onto VLC.

Comment: I may be speaking too soon, but upgrading to macOS 12.5 Beta (21G5037d) (Beta 2?) has fixed Blu-Ray crashes for me. Not sure what happened between then but I'm not experiencing crashes with an ISO that used to crash me. I can open the BDMV stream folder, quicklook (play the video) it, and use FFmpeg on it! I hope it stays like that in the future

Answer (score 2):

> "panicString" : "panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe002580c9e4):
> vm_object_iopl_request: missing/bad page in kernel object
> @vm_pageout.c:9356

From your initial panic report, it seems that you are hitting a synchronous panic during a request to the virtual memory subsystem to create a new I/O universal page list. This, alone, doesn't tell us enough. We need to gather further information to get nearer to the root cause.

Zooming out for a moment: You are clearly encountering a bug in macOS because – by definition and design! – it must be *impossible* for an unprivileged user to induce a kernel panic, especially one with 100% reproducibility like this. **This bug is ultimately Apple's fault.** Without additional debugging (which requires custom tools and access to Apple's proprietary source code), you are unlikely to determine root cause and are guaranteed to not be able to effect a true fix to the underlying issue (which would require making a change to `xnu` and/or other codebases). This is not surprising, as both Monterey and the M1 Pro are new and there are often bugs at release time.

This means that, for now, your best bet is to

1. Gather as much information as you can,
2. [Report the bug to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) with all of the information from #1, and
3. Try to find a short-term workaround while Apple investigates and fixes this bug.

The first step in gathering more information is to make your panic report more useful. This means two things:

- Don't omit the list of loaded KEXTs (or any other information) from your report; every line in a panic report was intentionally put in because it can contain an important and subtle clue about the root cause.
- We need to collect a new panic report with **kernel symbolication** enabled so that the backtrace can tell us what call chain led to the VM panic.

To enable symbolication:

1. Run the following Terminal command:

   **`sudo nvram boot-args="keepsyms=1"`**

   Make sure to copy-paste this so that you're entering straight quotes rather than curly/“smart” quotes. (If you get a general error, you will first need to **[disable System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection)**. You can re-enable it after you're done with this investigation.)
2. Reboot your machine. The next time this panic occurs, your report will have a symbolicated backtrace. Please amend your question with a new link to it.

Comment: Wait, am I supposed to enable SIP directly after I change the nvram boot arg or crash it, get report and then reenable SIP, and is it OK to leave 'syms=1' as is? I went to recovery, disabled SIP; booted as normal to change the nvram boot-arg, then back to recovery to enable SIP which took an indefinite amount of time so I ended the process. I've tried to kernel panic my laptop again but it won't restart on it's own, it will simply generate a spindump log.

Comment: @Meh. SIP needs to be disabled only to make changes to NVRAM. Otherwise its state is irrelevant for the actual investigation. The important part is for you to be running with symbolication enabled. You can test whether this is the case via `sysctl kern.bootargs`.

Comment: I think this is somehow related to the Youtube HDR-Video crash, and the new Monterey 12.1 Public Beta release MIGHT address this. If not, I'm praying for a fix before macOS 13.

Comment: updated to 12.1, **this bug did not get fixed.**

Comment: @Meh. It is incredibly unlikely for Apple to issue a fix to a bug that was reported only 5 days ago unless it is an absolute and widespread disaster. There is a very long bug queue for every engineer at the company. It takes (sometimes significant) time to research, reproduce, root cause, fix, and test-test-test before a bug gets bundled up into a software update delivery vehicle. Especially if you are the only person to submit this particular bug report, be prepared to wait quite a while. If you’re interested in trying to research and root-cause it yourself, LMK and we can resume the process.

Comment: I thought it was connected to HDR playback, so I was hoping it got fixed. I'd like to commit research on the bug, but at the same time I'm not sure if kernel-panicking my mac multiple times is a safe thing? I feel like something's gonna corrupt if it panicks way too much. Here is an update however: I created a folder on my desktop and ran `touch test.m2ts` without a crash (I even quicklook'd it). I also used a normal DVDISO which runs on the `.VOB` format. When I opened a `.iso` file with that, my mac did not panic.

Comment: Ok, I decided to go more indepth. Creating a ISO with the empty `.m2ts` does nothing. I also tried enabling keepsyms again and discovered the hard way that enabling `csrutil` wipes your boot args AND removed my fancy `touch ID sudo` edit! This crash was with csrutil off the entire time: https://paste.ee/p/WNweU, so I could have `keepsyms=1` on. I verified it was on before & after the crash, but I can't tell if symbolication is enabled.

Comment: More experimentation: I tried to copy the BDMV folder which contains the STREAMS folder (all of the m2ts) and that also causes a crash. I can use handbrake to read the ISO in question (and extract the m2ts files reencoded as mp4) but Handbrake reencodes it. I purely want FFmpeg to do it as I can see and control what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Also having this same issue with both my M1 Mac mini and my 14" M1 MacBook Pro (I was hoping it was an issue isolated to the M1 Mac mini (which I'd been experiencing since purchase in November 2020.

All I want to be able to do is extract the .m2ts file so that I can convert it to an MKV but as soon as I touch that file or try to copy the entire BDMV folder the whole machine will crash and reboot.

Does anyone know of any other ways of mounting the image file in MacOS other than the built in software?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/317039)