# New M1 MBP Monterey Kernel Panic

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

I keep having my new M1 MBP restart on me for the following inscrutable reason, please help:

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffe0023515638): Too many alloc retries: 502, table:0xfffffe0026eeb560, type:3, nelem:1 @ltable.c:489
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 21A559
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:01 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 3B2CA3833A09A383D66FB36667ED9CBF
Kernel UUID: 67BCB41B-BAA4-3634-8E51-B0210457E324
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.5
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001bb94000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0022b98000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001c3bc000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe00233c0000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x000000001c4a4000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe00234a8000
mach_absolute_time: 0x395f572239
...
Bitmaps   : 0xfffffe774797c000 - 0xfffffe774d3e0000
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
...
CORE 0 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
...
Panicked task 0xfffffe152411cd50: 135816 pages, 13 threads: pid 2045: reMarkable
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe1514fb8e60, backtrace: 0xfffffe60b9c33320, tid: 68072
...
last started kext at 572835036: com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15 (addr 0xfffffe0022d7bc90, size 14976)
loaded kexts:
...
```

Comment: Please see the second half of my answer in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/431973/how-do-i-prevent-a-crash-when-interacting-with-blu-ray-videos/432015?noredirect=1#comment619629_432015. We need to see a symbolicated (and unabridged) panic report.

Comment: Sure @pion the full report is here: https://pastebin.com/YHkauacx
Thanks

Comment: Please note the part I mentioned in significant detail about needing a **symbolicated** report.

Comment: I've had 3 of these in the past hour. Just running Chrome and Midnight Commander (doing FTP with the latter). This is on an M1 Mac Mini that I got about a week ago from Apple; before that I had an Intel Mac Mini which almost never gave any problems.